# In bip32-utils for bitcoinjs, node.getAddress is not a function

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoinjs

I am trying to run the example code in the bip32-utils taken here (https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip32-utils) of:

```
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
const bip32utils = require('bip32-utils')

let mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic()
let seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic)

let hdNode = bitcoin.bip32.fromSeed(seed)

let childNode = hdNode.deriveHardened(0)
let external = childNode.derive(0)
let internal = childNode.derive(1)
let account = new bip32utils.Account([
  new bip32utils.Chain(external.neutered()),
  new bip32utils.Chain(internal.neutered())
])

console.log(account.getChainAddress(0))
```

But i keep getting this typeError of `node.getAddress is not a function`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoinjs-lib no longer contains the BIP-32 functionality you are trying to use:

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/commit/84bc2ea6bf62ddb26fa9cb023b765d414f98f982

You need to use https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip32